# React Native: Extend WebView

Tags: android, react-native, webview, super, subclassing

(Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811428/react-native-webview-getusermedia-not-working-onpermissionrequest-override))

I'd like to create a component in React Native that has exactly the same functionality that the native WebView, just overriding some of its methods.

I've followed the tutorials in React Native page, [with modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) and [UI Views](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) (which I think is the correct approach), but I'm not able to get what I'd like.

What I have been able to do:

```
// .../com/project/permissionwebview/    
public class PermissionWebviewView extends LinearLayout{

    private Context context;

    public PermissionWebviewView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        inflate(this.context, R.layout.permissionwebview, this);
    }
}
```

And my View manager:

```
// .../com/project/permissionwebview
public class PermissionWebviewViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<PermissionWebviewView> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "PermissionWebviewViewManager";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public PermissionWebviewView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        return new PermissionWebviewView(context); //If your customview has more constructor parameters pass it from here.
    }
}
```

The XML of the layout:

```
// .../res/layout/permissionwebview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/permission_webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to call it from React Native, but nothing is shown and nothing happens.

What I want is simply a custom element which calls the native one (in this case, `WebView`), so it renders exactly the same (same props, same methods), just overriding some of its methods when necessary (in my case, `onPermissionRequest()`).

Which would be the correct approach? How (and where) do I invoke the parent/super WebView?

### EDIT 1

I think I've made it run, but **I don't know if it's the correct approach**, as I still don't know **how to pass all the parameters** from React Native component (`<PermissionWebview />`) to the native `WebView` element:

```
// .../com/project/permissionwebview/
public class PermissionWebviewView extends LinearLayout{

    private Context context;
    private WebView myWebView;

    public PermissionWebviewView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        inflate(this.context, R.layout.permissionwebview, this);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.permission_webview);

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://staticWebSite.Until/Parameters/Are/Passed");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to ultimately get an extended `WebView` working on Android by starting with this information in the [react-native-website](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/custom-webview-android.md) repo on GitHub. A lot of this code comes from both the sample at the link as well as the actual React Native implementation of `WebView`.

I plan to submit a pull request with some changes that I needed to do in order to actually build the Java, and also to retrieve the needed reference to the actual `WebView` that I'm wrapping (not everyone will need this).

Note that some of the classes are nested and the names need to be further qualified than in the example from GitHub:

Here is what I had to do. In my case I needed to add App Cache Manifest functionality to the `WebView`. You probably won't need to have all of these import statements, and may need to add others:

CustomWebViewManager.java:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

import com.facebook.react.common.build.ReactBuildConfig;
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.WebViewConfig;
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager;

@ReactModule(name = CustomWebViewManager.REACT_CLASS)
public class CustomWebViewManager extends ReactWebViewManager {
  protected static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyCustomWebView";

  protected static class CustomReactWebViewClient extends ReactWebViewManager.ReactWebViewClient { }

  protected static class CustomReactWebView extends ReactWebViewManager.ReactWebView {
    public CustomReactWebView(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
    }
  }

  public CustomWebViewManager() {
    mWebViewConfig = new WebViewConfig() {
      public void configWebView(WebView webView) {
      }
    };
  }

  public CustomWebViewManager(WebViewConfig webViewConfig) {
    mWebViewConfig = webViewConfig;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactWebView createReactWebViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new CustomReactWebView(reactContext);
  }

  // I had to override this in order to enable my needed WebView functionality
  @Override
  protected WebView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    ReactWebView webView = createReactWebViewInstance(reactContext);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage message) {
        if (ReactBuildConfig.DEBUG) {
          return super.onConsoleMessage(message);
        }
        // Ignore console logs in non debug builds.
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
      }
    });
    reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(webView);
    mWebViewConfig.configWebView(webView);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    // not sure if the below is needed, but at least one post indicated that it was so I did this with my package name to be safe
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("data/data/<your package name here>/cache");
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    // Fixes broken full-screen modals/galleries due to body height being 0.
    webView.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    if (ReactBuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    return webView;
  }

  @Override
  protected void addEventEmitters(ThemedReactContext reactContext, WebView view) {
    // Do not register default touch emitter and let WebView implementation handle touches
    view.setWebViewClient(new CustomReactWebViewClient());
  }
}
```

CustomWebViewPackage.java

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
  import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
  import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
  import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

  public class CustomWebViewPackage implements ReactPackage {
      @Override
      public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }

      @Override
      public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(new CustomWebViewManager());
      }
  }
```

CustomWebView.jsx

```
  'use strict';

  import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import * as React from 'react';
  import {
    requireNativeComponent,
    WebView
  } from 'react-native';

  /**
   * Renders a native WebView via our custom wrapper. 
   * Necessary because the RN WebView does not turn on the App Cache functionality by default. 
   * Can't make this a .tsx file due to TS problems around spreading the this.props into the child WebView.
   */
  class CustomWebView extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = WebView.propTypes;

    render() {
      return (
        <WebView 
          {...this.props}
          ref={(view) => {
            this.props.wrappedRef(view);
          }}
          nativeConfig={{component: MyCustomWebView}} 
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const MyCustomWebView = requireNativeComponent('MyCustomWebView', CustomWebView, 
    WebView.extraNativeComponentConfig);

  export default CustomWebView;
```

Note the `wrappedRef` property. I added this because the consumer of my `CustomWebView` needs a reference to the `WebView` that's actually being rendered. This was due to it needing to reference functionality there such as `postMessage()`. The consumer passes an arrow function which sets the reference to a property in the consuming class. That function is invoked in what is passed to `ref` as you can see.

Comment: Do you have an ios implementaion aswell ?

Comment: @Kaushik no sorry.