# Can't access to camera through react-native-webview

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview

I am using `react-native-webview` version 4.0.2 . So I have a webview that contains an add button that allows us to take picture with the camera but when clicking at that button nothing is shown and no camera permission shown. This is on android side but working very well on ios (i can see permission and access to camera ).

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I do have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

So please do you  have any suggestion ?

Comment: Check the answer posted here. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789794/1161998

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```java
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="23"
    android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: i have tried your code ousama but not working still no camera permissions

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/719)? I hope you'll get something out of it.

Answer (score 4):

1st step:
use this in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

2nd step:
Grant multiple permission in App.js file

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
]);
```

3rd step:
use these properties inside webview

```
geolocationEnabled={true}
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're serving a site that isn't through localhost, then this ***isn't possible locally***. Chrome **rejects** all non-localhost/non-https for device (camera) access!

Here's the story:

I created a Webview with local information:

I injected the HTML and loaded a third-party JavaScript file into the WebView (Through an import via unpkg).

`navigator.getUserMedia` is undefined when not served via https or localhost.

When developing in React Native, you won't always have access to localhost (especially if you're developing via WiFi using your phone).

**Solution**
Host the content on a remote backend and serve it through https.

Comment: Thx alot man. It's save me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this too  inside webview mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}

Answer (score 0):

If you use Expo, in my case, temporarily, I solve it by doing this. In the website's code, not the react-native code, change

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video : true, audio:true})
```

to

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video : true})
```

In the long term, if you use Expo, you should switch to React Native cli